# In QGIS: NetCDF image too pixelated

Tags: qgis, netcdf, image

When i import NetCDF file (.nc) to QGIS then I get a picture that consists of quite big pixels. Is it somehow possible to soften those pixels to get something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want you want to make the boundaries look smoother you can apply a low pass smoothing filter or a Gaussian filter using SAGA in QGIS, e.g.:

[image]

To find these filters in QGIS follow this path:
`Processing Toolbox -> SAGA -> Raster Filter -> Gaussian filter` or `Simple Filter`

Keep in mind though that they will change your data values.